# Storing DOM elements that are used throughout the code

Tags: javascript, object, variables, dom

Assume we have some DOM elements that need to be accessible throughout the code. There are also some states whose values need to be used in all functions. Which one is considered a better approach?

This?

```
// Long list of elements
var container1 = document.getElementById('container1');
var btn1 = document.getElementById('button1');
// ...
var container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('button2'); 
// ...
var state1, state2;

function doSomeThing1() {
  // Do something with the above elements and variables
  // Produce state1
}

function doSomeThing2() {
  // Do something with the above elements and variables
  // Produce state2
}
```

Or this?

```
const myObj1 = {
  container : document.getElementById('container1'),
  btn : document.getElementById('button1'),
  // ...
  state: null,

  doSomeThing() {
  // Do something with the above elements and myObj2 properties
  // Produce state
  },
};

const myObj2 = {
  container : document.getElementById('container2'),
  btn : document.getElementById('button2'),
  // ...
  state: null,

  doSomeThing() {
  // Do something with the above elements and myObj1 properties
  // Produce state
  },
};
```

I'm trying to avoid global variables, but the DOM elements need to be accessible everywhere. I'm also worried that using objects is a bad idea.

Comment: A common solution to this is the use of an [**IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: DOM elements are objects themself, they have attributes, properties. Depending on what you're trying to do, it may be more appropriate to keep track of an element's state using its attributes and properties instead of other loos variables.

Comment: Note that making a reference to an element and hanging on to it is a good path to memory leaks. Better to just query the document for the element when you need it. If you use IDs, these are basically instant lookups in a hash table by the browser.

Comment: But this question is asking for opinions. The "best" approach is the one that works for you and your team. If you think one might be slower, test it.

Answer (score -1):

Use standard events such as `.click` or `.focus` to track element states and events. See [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

In terms of storing references to specific DOM elements, just declare the variable once and use that reference as required later on. For example `var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button")`, then use `myButton` whenever you want.

Comment: So would it be ok if I declared global variables pointing to those elements?

Comment: Yes, ...but the issue is: what happens when your code gets to be 1,500 line long? Practically speaking it can get difficult to manage. It's easiest to select the element at the codeblock that it is used in - even if that means selecting it multiple times throughout your code. That's been my experience.